# tracking values in a listbox in vb.net through the index values

Tags: vb.net

How can I track the first value in a listbox, or use the value in the listbox to solve a problem, I tried using this:

```
Dim I as integer;    
Dim N,X as double;    
N=listbox1.item.count;    
For i=0 to N-1;   
    X=listbox1.item(0);    
Next I;    
Lbldata.text=X.Tostring();
```

Comment: Winforms?  Web?  etc?

Comment: that is not valid VB code

Comment: @Plutonix It's VB#  :-)

Comment: and pronounced "VB Hashtag"

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `listbox1.ITEMS.item(0)`

```
Dim I as integer  
Dim N,X as double    
N=listbox1.items.count   
For i=0 to N-1  
    X=listbox1.items.item(0)  
Next I   
Lbldata.text=listbox1.items.item(X).Tostring()
```

why all these ";" ? is this really vb.net?
i kinda fixed your code but it doesn't see to make much sense. I guess what you want is simply this:

```
Lbldata.text=listbox1.items.item(0)
```

Comment: Assuming Winforms, the code is just `listBox1.Items(0)`